# Firebase Snapshot Isn't showing Data

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Basically everything is working, except the showChild func is returning completion([]) because of the guard catData = Category(snapshot: catInfo). I am wondering why the guard let is returning completion. When I debug, catInfo does have 1 value as shown in my pic of database and I want to append catData.main to "cats". Below is code for the service method and Category model as well.

[Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6XWQ.png)

```
static func showChild(completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("category").child(User.current.uid)
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {
            return completion([])
        }

        var cats = [String]()

        for catInfo in snapshot {
            guard let catData = Category(snapshot: catInfo) else {
                return completion([])
            }
            cats += catData.main
        }
        completion(cats)
    })
}

import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase.FIRDataSnapshot

class Category {

    var key: String?
    let main: [String]

    init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        guard !snapshot.key.isEmpty else {return nil}
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : Any]{

            let main = dict["main"] as? [String]

            self.key = snapshot.key
            self.main = main ?? [""]
        }
        else{
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don’t include images or links in your questions. Include code and structures as text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is pretty straightforward.

While your snapshot contains at least one node of data, it's not in a format that the Category init method understands. You're iterating over it's child nodes and in your screenshot, there's only one, with a key of 'main'

You are observing this node

```
fb_root
   category
      2ayHe...
```

and then you're iterating over it's child nodes which will be

```
main
   0: Performance
```

so the key is 'main' and it's value is '0: Performance'

but your Category class is looking for a child node of 'main'

```
let main = dict["main"] as? [String]
```

There's not enough info to understand what will be contained in the rest of the structure so I can't tell you how to correct it, but at least you know what the problem is.

To clarify, this line

```
if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : Any]
```

will make dict = [0: "Performance]